# Can we choose real eigenvectors for a real matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a diagonalizable matrix with $B \in GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ such that $B^{-1}AB$ is diagonal. Let $v_1,\dots,v_n \in \mathbb{C}^n$ be the column vectors of $B$:
\begin{equation*}
B=
\left(\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
v_1 & v_2 &\dots& v_n
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}

Then $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are eigenvectors of $A$, and if we choose $z_1,\dots,z_n \in \mathbb{C}$ nonzero complex numbers, and build the following matrix:
\begin{equation*}
C=
\left(\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
z_1 v_1 & z_2 v_2 &\dots& z_n v_n
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}

Then $C^{-1}AC$ is diagonal. Can we choose $z_1,\dots,z_n \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $C\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general this is of course not possible, because real eigenvectors of real matrices of course lead to real eigenvalues. Thus it is only possible if all eigenvalues are real.